Accord du participe passé avec avoir
Voici deux phrases dont j'aimerais savoir s'il faut accorder le participe passé et pourquoi. Dans les deux cas, le complément est censé être féminin. D'après les règles habituelles, je les accorderais.

Tout ce qui t'a épouvanté(e).

Il l'a cru(e) porteuse d'un signe.



Le participe passé employé avec l'auxiliaire avoir s'accorde avec le complément d'objet direct (t' et l') quand celui-ci est placé avant le verbe. C'est bien le cas ici donc accord:

Tout ce qui t'a épouvantée.

Il l'a crue porteuse d'un signe.



Un moyen enseigné à l'école pour identifier le le complément d'objet direct est de transformer l'affirmation en une question à la forme passive  : Qui a été épouvanté ? => t'. Qui a-t-il crue porteuse d'un signe ? => l'
